# Python regex for matching odd number of consecutive backslashes

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all odd number of continuous backslashes.

I tried the following expression:

```
(?<!\\)(\\)(?!\\)
```

However, it matches a single backslash if present.

Comment: Try `r'(?<!\\)\\(?:\\{2})*(?!\\)'`

Comment: i tired (?<!\\)\\(?!\\) but it matches only a if a single backslash is present

Comment: Format code by either wrapping it in `` ` `` or putting it on its own line and putting four spaces in front.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this too:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\(?!\\)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qYldoN/2)

1. `(?<!\\)` No backslash in the back from the current location
2. `(?:\\{2})` matches each next consecutive pairs of backslash , zero
   or more occasion
3. `\\` matches a single backslash
4. `(?!\\)` then checks if there is no more backslash immediately

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
r'(?<!\\)\\(?:\\{2})*(?!\\)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouKzAZ/1).

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\)` - no backslash can appear right before the current location
- `\\` - a single backslash
- `(?:\\{2})*` - 0 or more occurrences of 2 backslashes
- `(?!\\)` - no `\` can appear immediately to the right at the current location.

Note that in Python it is a good idea to use raw string literal when using literal backslashes in a regex pattern (to reduce the number of escapes and make the pattern look tidier, and avoid any issues related to misinterpreted backslashes.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for speed, this benchmarks the best:
`\\(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\)*(?!\\)`

```
Regex1:   \\(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\)*(?!\\)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.23 s,   229.23 ms,   229231 µs

Regex2:   (?<!\\)\\(?:\\{2})*(?!\\)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.83 s,   829.68 ms,   829684 µs

Regex3:   (?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\(?!\\)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    1.09 s,   1086.34 ms,   1086340 µs
```